# What is the unit of the ruler in Android studio layout editor?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]
What is the unit of the ruler in Android studio layout editor?

I chose Nexus 5 and the screen size of Nexus 5 is `360dp x 640dp` or `1080px x 1920px`

It's neither dp nor px.  What is it? Can I change the unit?

Comment: how to enable ruler??

Comment: I think they have removed this function from the latest version of AS.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's dp fixed in xhdpi screen. You can see when select Nexus 5 (1080px width), its screen take approx 550 unit in horizontal ruler.